# Rearrangement inequality in cyclic but non-symmetric inequality

Tags: inequality

Applying the rearrangement inequality usually involves introducing ordering in the variables of the inequality. This must be done without loss of generality. Now, I understand that if the inequality is symmetric ie unchanged by swapping any variables, then introducing any ordering does not lead to a loss of generality.

However, I have also seen the rearrangement inequality applied to inequalities that are cyclic but *non-symmetric*, for instance

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(a+b)} \geq \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(a+c)}$$

Now, this is almost trivial if we are allowed to introduce ordering in $a, b, c$ that is assume $a\geq b\geq c$. But how is this not loss of generality?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \le y \le z$ be an increasing permutation of the (positive) numbers $a, b, c$ and $s := a+b+c = x+y+z$.
 Then
$$
\frac 1z \le \frac 1y \le \frac 1x \text{ is an increasing permutation of} \frac 1b ,  \frac 1c ,  \frac 1a
$$
and
$$
 \frac 1{s-x} \ge \frac 1{s-y} \ge \frac 1{s-x}
\text{ is a decreasing permutation of} 
\frac 1{s-c} ,  \frac 1{s-a} ,  \frac 1{s-b} \, .
$$

It follows from the rearrangement inequality that
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(a+c)} = \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(s-b)} =
 \frac{1}{x(s-x)} +  \frac{1}{y(s-y)} +  \frac{1}{z(s-z)} \\
 \le \frac{1}{b(s-c)} +  \frac{1}{c(s-a)} +  \frac{1}{a(s-b)} \\
 = \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(s-c)} = \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(a+b)} 
$$